# Getting identifier expected error

Tags: java

I am having a problem with creating an object inside a thread i have tried it removing the creation of the new Thread and then it works fine however i need the thread there for later processes.

```
...
    Thread add = new Thread(){   
        Editor tool = new Editor();
        tool.addModule("modules.csv");
    } 
....
```

The class Editor does exists and both the editor and class the code extract is from extend Thread, however the only error message that i get is that identifier is expected. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Please review some Java syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to dump what appear to be the intended contents of the `run()` method into the class body. The actual code that you've posted looks essentially useless, but I think you meant

```
Thread add = new Thread() {
    @Override public void run() {
        Editor tool = new Editor();
        tool.addModule("modules.csv");
    }
}
```

I highly recommend using an IDE such as Eclipse; not only would it have caught and explained this error, it would have given you the appropriate skeleton in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The below should work :

```
Thread add = new Thread(){

        @Override public void run() 
        {   
           Editor tool = new Editor();
           tool.addModule("modules.csv");
        } 
    }
```

A few more recommendations :

1. Understand Java syntax
2. Read about anonymous classes - in fact what you are doing here is creating an anonymous class that extends **java.lang.Thread**.
3. Use an IDE ( as stated in the response by **chrylis**) - helps you immediately understand syntax errors.
4. If you are using the later versions of Java, I would recommend to go ahead and use [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). This provides a clean way to segregate the concurrency related aspects from the actual business logic.